# How to remove all physical bodies from physical

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics

I'm working on a corona project and I now want to remove all bodies from the physics.

I see it has only a method to remove a body but not all

```
physics.removeBody()
```

I need to remove all, like that

```
 physics.removeAllBodies()
```

Who can give me a way to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify: a physical object does not have multiple bodies, are you talking about a display group? Maybe show the code where you create your physical bodies (don't need the details of options etc) and what you would like to do.

Comment: My English skill is too bad, so, it may make you don't understant my question. I mean, I want to remove all bodies from the physics manager. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is to add each display body to a physicsBodies table whenever you add to physics:

```
local physicsDisplayObjects = {}

...

function scene:createScene(event)
    ...
    local displayObject1 = ... -- display object
    physics.addBody(displayObject1, ...) -- transform it into a physics body
    table.insert(physicsDisplayObjects, displayObject1)
    ...
end

...

function something()
    ...
    for i,obj in ipairs(physicsDisplayObjects) do 
        physics.removeBody(obj) -- revert obj into regular display object
    end
    physicsDisplayObjects = {} -- clear
    ...
end

...
```